# How can I find policy recommendations as well as scholarly researches on the relationship of "conflict of interest" and "poverty reduction efforts"?

Tags: government, reference-request, poverty, conflict-of-interest, social-policy

I want to find policy recommendations as well as scholarly researches on the relationship of "conflict of interest" and "poverty reduction efforts". It seems that there exists vast amount of literature on the interrelation of corruption and poverty but I could not find papers directly addressing the aforementioned issue. what should I do?

Comment: Please specify, (or provide representative examples of), **whose** conflicted interests might be relevant to this question.

Comment: Conflict of national and local interests manifested in the actions of parliament members can be mentioned as a prevalent instance of conflict of interest, allocating resources to inappropriate uses and intensifying poverty.
I want to find solutions from international experiences.

Comment: From the top of my mind the closest I can think of is The Dictators Handbook, where the last chapter is about this (If I understand the question correct). The book is itself isn't scholarly research but the authors are scientists.